# Translation of locality

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I've implemented client-side geocoding according the the official documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

It works all fine, however, there's one shortcoming: The results are always in one language, the language requested by use of the `language` param.

What I need is the locality translated in several languages, namely the languages our website is available in. Here's an example: The search for "Geneva" yields a result locality depending on the `language` param:

- `en`: Geneva
- `de`: Genf
- `fr`: Genève

Is there a way to get all three translations with only one API call or do I have to fetch the translations separately?

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only with separate calls, because you can't set multiple languages to the request query.

But why you need all supported languages at once? If the user selected one language it should be just fine to use this one through the session or till another language is choosen.

Comment: The locality is used for tagging and I have to translate the tags in all of the three available locales.

Comment: Well, than you have to make 3 calls. Or you translate the city names with a Translator API like Google Translate or Bing Translation.